# mysql automation through expect

Tags: mysql, expect

i need to automate `mysql_secure_installation` process, i have written this script but its failing miserably,, i dont want to set any passwrd for database

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10
spawn mysql_secure_installation

expect "Enter current password for root (enter for none):"
send -- "\r"
expect "Set root password? [Y/n]"
send  "n\r"
expect "Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]"
send  "Y\r"
expect "Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n]"
send  "n\r"
expect "Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n]"
send "Y\r"
expect "Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n]"
send  "Y\r"
interact
```

Error:

```
[root@localhost ansible]# ./mysql.sh
spawn mysql_secure_installation

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): invalid command name "Y/n"
    while executing
"Y/n"
    invoked from within
"expect "Set root password? [Y/n]""
    (file "./mysql.sh" line 8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is special in TCL, and `"..."` interpolates, so

```
"blah [foo]"
```

causes TCL to attempt to call the `foo` procedure (`proc`, or what other languages might call a `sub` or `function`). One can either backwhack the `[`

```
expect "blah \[foo]"
```

or instead quote with `{}` which disables interpolation

```
expect {blah [foo]}
```

Those are the sane options. Do not use any code past this point!

**The Ministry of Silly Procs**

We can also create a `proc` that causes a call to `Y/n` to return `[Y/n]`;

```
$ expect
expect1.1> proc Y/n {} { return "\[Y/n]" }
expect1.2> puts "abort [Y/n]"
abort [Y/n]
expect1.3>
```

this allows `[Y/n]` to operate within an interpolated string. Even more trouble can be gotten into via `unknown(n)` as this allows us to create a `proc` for most any random `[...]` string interpolated anywhere...unless of course a `proc` already exists for the given procedure name; like I said earlier, this is a bad idea and should not be used.

```
expect1.1> proc unknown args { return "\[$args]" }
expect1.2> puts "abort [Y/n]"
abort [Y/n]
expect1.3> puts "already exists [puts -nonewline puts\ ]"
puts already exists 
expect1.4>
```

Comment: even i  figured it out after alot of search, but  u cleared my concept of how actually that works,, thanks alot mate!!